How to stop NgRx effect if NgRx state already have the data in Angular
I am using #angular ngrx to make a http call to store the data in the state. Now, I want to stop the callout if ngrx state already have the data using RxJs like takeuntil etc.
Can someone please help me with an example?
In the below code I am not able to stop the http callout.
@Effect()
  fetchShippingContacts$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<picklistActions.RetrieveShippingContacts>(picklistActions.PicklistActionTypes.RetrieveShippingContacts)
    .map((action: picklistActions.RetrieveShippingContacts) => null)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .switchMap(() => {
      const nextSearch$ = this.actions$.ofType(picklistActions.PicklistActionTypes.RetrieveShippingContacts).skip(1);
      return this.vf.callRemoteAction([],
        environment.getShippingContacts.class,
        environment.getShippingContacts.method, true)
        .takeUntil(nextSearch$)
        .switchMap((response) => {
          console.log('response => ', response);
          return [
            new picklistActions.RetrieveShippingContactsComplete(shippingContactsPayloadParser(response.vfResponse.payloadMap.records)),
            new applicationActions.HideLoadingAllAction()
          ];
        })
        .catch((err) => from([
          new applicationActions.HideLoadingAllAction()
        ]));
    });

I have tried to stop the callout using takeUntil but using that also I am not able to stop the call.
Expectation:
For first time effect should call and ngrx state will update. If the Action is re-trigger and state already have the data then don't make http call or stop the effect.

Doing it a little bit different makes this easier.
If you don't want to execute the effect when there's already data into the store, you can use a filter to ignore the action.
For more info see a blog post that I wrote around this topic at https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#enhance-your-action-with-global-store-state
detail = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(ProductDetailPage.loaded),
    concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(selectProducts)),
    //  ignore if state is already in the store
    filter(([{ payload }, products]) => !!products[payload.sku]),
    mergeMap(([{payload}]) => {
      ...
    })
  )
})

